# Claim Based Authentication in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, claims-based-auth

I have created one Claim based authentication web application in sharepoint 2013. I have done all configuration from this link.. 
http://blog.morg.nl/2011/08/step-by-step-forms-based-authentication-fba-on-sharepoint-2010/ 
But i can't login through FBA Users. Username and password are correct but It gives error:

> "The server could not sign you in. Make sure your user name and
>   password are correct, and then try again"

Answer (score 0):

Have you added users to the database? If so make sure to Return the Default Provider for the .NET users to **“i”**  and for the .NET Roles to **“c”** after you ave added the users.

Comment: thanx @Joss_24. I set i & c in web application in iis. but not working. it always gives error in sign out page..

Comment: can you check in central administration if can add some fba user as a site collection administrator, do the same logged as windows on the site, try to add some fba user in some group.
if you can do both task, the problem is in the sts

Comment: have you tried debugging the login page solution. whats the error message in logs indicate ?